# 'better utilization' with or without article

Tags: articles

I have the following sentences:

1. "Optimization methods can lead to (**a**) better utilization of renewable energy sources"
2. "Optimization methods lead to (**a**) better utilization of
   renewable energy sources"

My question is, whether it is a mistake to use the article 'a' in this context. I used to have the articcle there but Grammarly tells me to get rid of it. As something like this can be found frequently in my thesis, I'd appreciate it if anyone could comment on my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilization can be used both as a countable and as an uncountable noun.

If you're using it in the uncountable sense (as it seems to be the case) it is not grammatical to use an indefinite article.

Either leave the article out or use the definite article "The" depending on the context

Comment: Thanks Arunkgp for your answer (I accepted it). I have a follow-up question regarding the sentence ''The methods lead to higher (a) usage of locally generated PV." Would you also leave the article (a) out in this sentence? I'd really appreciate a comment from you (or someone else)

Comment: I presume you're asking me whether it should be "higher usage" or "a higher usage". One of the definitions of "Usage" is "the amount/mode of use", therefore it's valid to use the expression a "higher/lower usage" to signify the rate/speed/amount of usage.

Comment: Thanks Arunkgp for your comment. So you would say "a higher usage" in this example if I understood correctly.

Comment: As long as you're talking about a higher amount/degree of usage, yes I would.

Comment: Thanks Arunkgp for your comment. Yes I am talking about a higher amount. What is the difference between usage and utilization? For utilization you told me not to use the 'a' before this. Basically utilization also means 'higher amount' in a broader way. And by the way, Grammarly tells me not to use the 'a' for both 'utilization' and 'higher usage' (I know that Grammarly is not always right; just wanted to mentione it).

Comment: Utilization is only colloquially used to mean "amount of use" whereas the formal definition of usage includes that possibility. You can google the Merriam Webster definition of "usage" where they specifically list "A decreased usage" as grammatically correct. Equate "utilization" to "practical use". You find that "a better practical use" more accurately describes a different more practical use, rather than the better application of the same use (Which is what I guessed you were going for).

Comment: Thanks Arunkgp for your comment. To be totally honest, I do not understand your last post. So you would not use 'a' for utilizaiton but you would use 'a' for 'higher/lower usage'?

Comment: If you're talking about just improving the rate/quality of utilization, I wouldn't say "a better utilization". If I'm talking about a completely different utilization, I would use "a". For instance. Using water for agriculture rather than for industry is a better utilization of water, whereas increasing the efficiency of the water used in Industry is better utilisation of water. The first is concerned with different utilisations (Agri or industry) and thus "a" is acceptable, whereas the second is dealing with the same utilisation (Agri) so "a" is misleading.

Comment: Thanks Arunkgp for your comment. Okay I understood your opinion on 'utilization'. But for the word 'usage' it seems that it is just the opposite, right? So you would use 'a higher usage' .

Comment: Since the definition for "Usage" includes "amount/mode of use", yes. "a higher usage" has the meaning you intended whereas "a better utilization" can be misleading is used in the same context.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a mistake but a choice. If you don't use it you do not insist on the possible fact that there exists a variety of ways of utilizing energy, in other words, a variety of utilizations; if you use the article, then you understate that there might  not be just  one single way of coming up with a better utilization , but several.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use *utilization* where *use* will do. In fact, swapping in *use* will help illustrate the difference between using an indefinite article and not, I think:

> *Optimization methods lead to a better use of renewable energy sources.*
>
> *Optimization methods lead to better use of renewable energy sources.*

Can you see the difference in sense now? It's a bit subtle, but the first sentence reads as: *optimize and we'll use them for something else*. I think you mean the second sentence though: *optimize and we'll use them more efficiently*.

Comment: Thanks Tinfoil Hat for your answer. I do not really understand the first sentence. What I want to say is that optimization methods generally lead to (a) better utilization of renewable energies. This means that if optimizaiton methods are use, renewable energy can be used in a better way.

Comment: *Utilization* isn't the same thing as *use* in this context. You can't really go with *use* here, it should be *utilization*. *Utilization* is about increasing (or quantifying) the amount of resources deemed useful. *Use* refers to how they get used. Better optimization means more potentially profitable sites for wind turbines - improving utilization. It says nothing about what the electricity gets used for.

Comment: @PhilSweet: The noun *use* can always be used in place of *utilization*. https://eliteediting.com/resources/use-vs-utilize/

Comment: No it can't. *Utilization* is a metric, *use* is not a metric. Your link never mentions *utilization*. It only compares the verbs *use* and *utilize*, and states they are not the same either. And *use* can not always substitute for *utilize*. The link doesn't cover the meanings that are unique to utilize. "I used a frying pan as a weapon" means I still have a frypan. "I utilized a frying pan as a weapon" means I weaponized a frypan, and there is no reason to suppose it is still usable as a frypan - improvisation vs malicious intent.

Comment: @PhilSweet: To have used a frying pan as a weapon suggests nothing about the ownership, state, or usability of the frying pan as such; you're reading something into the proposition.